# xaml Twoway binding to a property in PhoneApplicationPage code behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

ok fairly simple, I have a ToggleSwitch on my page like so.

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="togLocation" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Style="{StaticResource gToggleSwitchStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource brLightFont}"
    Loaded="togLocation_Loaded" IsChecked="{Binding LocationTrackingEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

in the code behind of the same page I have the following

```
public partial class Setup : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public bool LocationTrackingEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(LocationTrackingEnabledProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LocationTrackingEnabledProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationTrackingEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LocationTrackingEnabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(Setup),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));

    // blah blah rest of the page code follows on
```

as you can see the default value is false so the toggleswitch.IsChecked should be false. Nope its true. Using breakpoint I check LocationTrackingEnabled and it never changes so clearly the binding does no work.

I have tried this in code behind.

```
DataContext = this;
```

I have also tried this in the xaml of the page

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I have done bindings before but I can't see the issue.

Comment: What is your parent class of the `LocationTrackingEnabled` property?

Comment: its a PhoneApplicationPage. So basically the toggleswitch that is on the page is binding to a property on the page created in code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for this to be a DependencyProperty.  Just use it as a regular property.  Also, check your debug output when you run-- if you have a binding issue, it will show up there.

Comment: no binding issue. As its twoway binding don't I need either DependencyProperty or use INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Are you sure the field is set to true, or are you basing this on the fact that the toggle is not set in the UI?  Can you put a TextBlock in there that also shows the value of the property?  One last thing... what's the style set to?  Try removing the style and see if it has any effect.

Comment: I put a textblock in and did element property bind to the toggle.IsSelected. In blend its set to false but when it loads up it changes to true. I put a break point on a button click event so I can see the LocationTrackingEnabled value, and its set to False. The style is just a visual style i.e. the colour of the control.

Comment: That is odd.  Not that you should have to do this, but try setting it to false some time after InitializeComponent in your constructor.  Also, I know you said that you tried both, but I would try this as a non-dependency property.  If it is still a problem, comment here, and I'll check late tonight.

Comment: I just created a project just like you have, and it works fine.  The only thing I could think of is that in your togLocation_Loaded method, you are setting the value to true.  You didn't post that portion of your code, so I can't tell.

Comment: You always know that a problem like this is because of something stupid. The code in the page is pretty long was from an old project. As you mentioned the togLocation_Loaded method I thought "no im not doing anything with that". Moments later I find the method and I'm actually binding to something else!!! What an idiot lol